# SmartyException : Fatal error: Type of SmartyCompilerException::$line must be int

Tags: php, smarty

I am new to Smarty and working on an old app. I got the following SmartyException :

> Fatal error: Type of SmartyCompilerException::$line must be int (as in class Exception) in /xxx/libs/sysplugins/smartycompilerexception.php on line 8.

I don't know where the problem comes from and to debug this (i have xdebug enabled, i am on PHP 8.1 and Smarty version 3.1.48).
This is an app that was created with smarty version 2, i am migrated it to version 3 through the SMartyBC.class.php.

I tried Xdebug, putting breakpoints in my template, bug i am not familiar at all with smarty...

Comment: This is a PHP version issue! Easy fix is to upgrade your Smarty.

Comment: Not that easy, I can't upgrade smarty because it's an old 2.xx smarty version application.